# Wordpress: Cannot edit in a table

Tags: wordpress

I am working in Wordpress version 5.4.1, in Gutenberg, with a table block and having trouble editing.

It is relatively simple setup.  One column of images another of text.  I need to edit and change one image and I find it cannot be edited through the visual editor. I cannot get to detail below table.  See image from the bottom of the editor.

[image]

Is this a bug, or am I doing something basic wrong.

BTW, I can edit the text and I can edit the HTML to change the image, but that is of course defeating the intent of the visual editor.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is missing information. What is this screenshot supposed to show? What table block (gutenberg?) are you using and how is it embedded and edited (which visual editor?) What detail below table you want to edit and what is it showing and why (Document -> Table)... Please keep in mind we are no clairvoyant ;)

Comment: Sorry, I have added that I am in Gutenberg.  The image is from the bottom of the editor (as indicated) and I am trying to change the image (as indicated).   Since I am showing the visual editor, therefore I am working in the visual editor, that seems also to be in my question.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the question is to be honest. Are you inbinding an reusable block? maybe you have to change it to a normal block to edit it, done via the context menu. What plugin are you using for the table block? That thing with the visual editor is still a mystery for me, I'm sorry that I don't get it... gutenberg itself is visual editor, you are showing us some text in the screenshot...

Comment: "I need to edit and change one image and I find it cannot be edited through the visual editor."  -- is that not clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you want to have a two column layout created with the Gutenberg Editor in Wordpress.

---

**Gutenberg: Columns Block for multi-column layouts**

There is the columns block for that (**layout**). This block is used to create multi column layouts. You can add it under "Layout Elements" -> "Columns" (https://wpdevelopment.courses/articles/a-list-of-all-default-gutenberg-blocks-in-wordpress-5-0/#layout). Use this block, it will ask you which column layout you want to choose. I think the two columns separated in the middle will be your choice. You can also set if the content should be vertically top, middle or bottom.

Inside the columns you now have "+" and can add an "Image", found under the common blocks (https://wpdevelopment.courses/articles/a-list-of-all-default-gutenberg-blocks-in-wordpress-5-0/#common-blocks), and upload or choose an image from your media library. Inside of the other column you can add your paragraph.

---

**Gutenberg: Table Block for tabular data in table format**

There is the table block for that (**formatting**: https://wpdevelopment.courses/articles/a-list-of-all-default-gutenberg-blocks-in-wordpress-5-0/#formatting). The times using tables for layouting thankfully are over since a long time. You should not use tables to create the layout of your website. They are and were only for data in table format, not for creating layouts.

---

**Is your image block not working?**

If you are using your image block, you cannot upload or add images form the media library? Please try deactivating all your plugins and change to a default wordpress theme (i.e. twentytwenty). Is the problem still occuring when using Gutenberg? You should check the console in your browser inspector if there are any errors.

---

**Your image block is just not working for one image?**

Try to delete that block and save the page. Clear all your caches and reload the page. After that, insert a new image block in your layout. If it is working now, there just was something wrong with this one block element.

---

Your image is not working inside a table block?

Are there any errors, have you tried deactivating all plugins and change to default theme? Are you really wanting to show data in the table, or do you want to set up a column layout? Maybe it would be better to use the columns block, if you want to achieve two column layout.